# Docker & Angular - Can not connect to local spring boot backend server from a angular based frontend docker container

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

1. I have a local backend server running on the port 8080
2. I have developed an angular ui project which communicates to this back end server
3. I have built docker container for the angular ui project
4. when i try to access the UI the api server call(back end call) fails with the error code 502 Bad Gateway

**Below is my proxy.config.json file**

```
{
    "/user/service": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel":"debug"
    }
  }
```

**nginx proxy configuartion in default.conf.template**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  server {

      listen 80;

      sendfile on;
       server_name  localhost;

      default_type application/octet-stream;

      server_tokens off;

      gzip on;
      gzip_http_version 1.1;
      gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
      gzip_min_length   1100;
      gzip_vary         on;
      gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
      gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
      gzip_comp_level   9;

      root /usr/share/nginx/html;

      location /user/service{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
      }
  }
}
```

**Docker file as follows**

````
# To run the container:
# npm run build:dev:href
# docker build -t vat-validation-ui .
# docker run -d -p 4200:80 vat-validation-ui

### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node AS builder


#set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder

RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine

## Copy the template file to nginx folder
COPY nginx/default.conf.template /etc/nginx

## Copy the website files to nginx root folder
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/vat-validation-ui /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD  /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"```


How can i achieve this or  Is it not possible to have connection between docker container and local back end rest server ?
````

Comment: `proxy.config.json` works with `ng serve` development server, you just have no such proxy in your app. you should send requests directly to backend container

Comment: @Andrei I am not running Back end server as a container its just  running in my localhost with port 8080 . In this case how can i tell the front end container to talk to my local server at port 8080. As per my understanding thats way i have  nginx configuration in default.conf.template. Sorry i am new to docker and angular